# How to put the product card next to each other instead of being put on a new line?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a fake website for a school project. So far, I'm creating a products page where I'll list out the products I'm selling. I've copied a template from w3schools which has worked so far, however I want to create multiple of this same card that will be placed next to each other. What happens when I paste the same template is the card is put on a different line.

I've tried using float:left and copying and pasting the template again however the template is placed beneath the first one on a separate line. How would I place them next to each other? I'm not sure where to start. I know that I can create multiple  next to each other but I don't know how I would apply it to this scenario. Any help would be appreciated.

Code I Copied

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
}

.price {
  color: grey;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.card button {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 12px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.card button:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2 style="text-align:center">Product Card</h2>

<div class="card">
  <img src="/w3images/jeans3.jpg" alt="Denim Jeans" style="width:100%">
  <h1>Tailored Jeans</h1>
  <p class="price">$19.99</p>
  <p>Some text about the jeans. Super slim and comfy lorem ipsum lorem jeansum. Lorem jeamsun denim lorem jeansum.</p>
  <p><button>Add to Cart</button></p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

My Code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Pet Store</title>
<style>
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}


/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

.button {
  background-color: #9B3240;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #D3B6C4;
}

.header {
  background-color: #DB912B;
}

p {
  font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.blackFriday {
  line-height: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: antiquewhite z-index: 1;
  font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.fadein {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
}


/*Animated Banner*/

.fadein img {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 12s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 12s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  33% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  53% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  33% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  53% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

#f1 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

#f2 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -8s;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#f3 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -4s;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}   

/*Shop Bar*/

.shopBar {
    background-color: #9B3240;
    height: 75px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
.Logo {
    float:left;
}
.storeName {
    float: left;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 75px;
    width: 25%;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;    
}

.petstorename {
    flex: 0 0 120px;
    font-size: 40px;
    padding-left:10px;
}
.holidays {
    font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 81px;
    /* [disabled]line-height: 64px; */
    text-align: center;
    padding:20px;
}

.rowspacing {
    padding:15px;
}
.circlespace img {
    padding: 5px;
    position: 10px;
}
.specialdogdeals {
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 33px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}
.footer {
    background-color: #D5C3C3;
    height: 75 px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top:100px;
}

.footer img {
padding:4px;
display:inline;
}
.buy {    
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
}
.buy2 {
    background-color:black;
    float: left;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
.buy3 {
    float: left;
    height: 500px;
    width: 33%;
}
.buy4 {
    float: right;
    height: 500px;
    width: 33%;
}
.buy5 {
    background-color: yellow;
    float:left;
    height:500px;
}

/*Products*/

.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
}

.price {
  color: grey;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding:20px;
}

.card button {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 12px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.card button:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.productName {
    font-size:68px;
    font-weight:lighter;
    padding:10px;

}

.productDes {
    padding:10px;
}

.newPrice {
 font-size: 32px; 
 color:#272727;
 font-weight:bold;
 padding:10px;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>


<center>
    <a href="blackfriday.html"><p class="blackFriday" style="background-color:#191616; color: white; font-weight:bold;">BLACK FRIDAY SALE!</p></a>
</center>
<div class="fadein">
    <img id="f3" src="banner2.jpg" alt="">
    <img id="f2" src="banner4.png" alt="">
    <img id="f1" src="banner5.jpg" alt="">
</div>

<!--Shop Bar-->
<!--*<div class="shopBar">
    <div class="Logo"><img src="Logo.png" height="75px;" alt=""/></div>
<div class="storeName"><p class="petstorename">Pet Store</p></div>
</div>-->

 <!--Buttons-->
<center>
    <p style="background-color:#9B3240; position:relative;"> <a href="index.html"><img class="Logo" src="Logo.png" height="55" alt=""/></a>
      <a href="food.html"><button class="button">food</button></a>
      <a href="toys.html"><button class="button">toys</button></a>
      <a href="pharmacy.html"><button class="button">pharmacy</button></a>
      <a href="holiday.html"><button class="button">holiday sale</button></a>
      <a href="about.html"><button class="button">about us</button></a>
    </p>
</center>

<!--Images-->
<!--Products-->
<p class="holidays">BLACK FRIDAY</p>

<center><p class="specialdogdeals">These Deals Won't Last Long!</p></center>

     <div class="card">
      <img src="collar.png" alt="Denim Jeans" style="width:100%">
      <p class="productName">Leather Collar</p>
      <p class="price">$<strike>9.99</strike> 
      <p class="newPrice">2.99</p></p>
      <p class="productDes">A comfty collar made with natural materials.</p>
      <p><button>Add to Cart</button></p>
      

     <div class="card">
      <img src="collar.png" alt="Denim Jeans" style="width:100%">
      <p class="productName">Leather Collar</p>
      <p class="price">$<strike>9.99</strike> 
      <p class="newPrice">2.99</p></p>
      <p class="productDes">A comfty collar made with natural materials.</p>
      <p><button>Add to Cart</button></p>
</div>
  

 
 
   

</div> 


<!--Footer-->
<div class="footer">
    <center>
        <p style="font-weight: bold; line-height:75px;"> 
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/"><img src="instagram.png"  width="25" height="25" alt=""/></a>
            <a href="https://www.twitter.com/"><img src="twitter.png" width="25" height="25" alt=""/></a>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com"><img src="facebook.png" width="25" height="25" alt=""/></a>
        <img src="support-dog-icon.png" width="35"  style="margin-left:50px; margin-right:10px;" alt=""/>Contact (578) 239-8980
        </p>
       
    </center>
</div>


</b
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to wrap your cards into another div, which will have the propertie display: flex;

in your html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="card">
        <img src="collar.png" alt="Denim Jeans" style="width:100%">
        <p class="productName">Leather Collar</p>
        <p class="price">$<strike>9.99</strike> 
        <p class="newPrice">2.99</p></p>
        <p class="productDes">A comfty collar made with natural materials.</p>
        <p><button>Add to Cart</button></p>
    </div>
        
  
       <div class="card">
        <img src="collar.png" alt="Denim Jeans" style="width:100%">
        <p class="productName">Leather Collar</p>
        <p class="price">$<strike>9.99</strike> 
        <p class="newPrice">2.99</p></p>
        <p class="productDes">A comfty collar made with natural materials.</p>
        <p><button>Add to Cart</button></p>
      </div>
</div>
```

in your css:

```
 .wrapper{
    /* width: 100%; */
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    justify-content:center; //there are several options to position
    align-items:center;
    flex-wrap: wrap; //if the display gets to small, the cards will automaticly position on a different line

}
.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  max-width: 300px;
  /* margin: auto; */ //no more need because parent controlls position.
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
}
```

final product:

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Pet Store</title>
<style>
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}


/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

.button {
  background-color: #9B3240;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #D3B6C4;
}

.header {
  background-color: #DB912B;
}

p {
  font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.blackFriday {
  line-height: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: antiquewhite z-index: 1;
  font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.fadein {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
}


/*Animated Banner*/

.fadein img {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 12s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 12s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  33% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  53% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  33% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  53% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

#f1 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

#f2 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -8s;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#f3 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -4s;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}   

/*Shop Bar*/

.shopBar {
    background-color: #9B3240;
    height: 75px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
.Logo {
    float:left;
}
.storeName {
    float: left;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 75px;
    width: 25%;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;    
}

.petstorename {
    flex: 0 0 120px;
    font-size: 40px;
    padding-left:10px;
}
.holidays {
    font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 81px;
    /* [disabled]line-height: 64px; */
    text-align: center;
    padding:20px;
}

.rowspacing {
    padding:15px;
}
.circlespace img {
    padding: 5px;
    position: 10px;
}
.specialdogdeals {
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 33px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}
.footer {
    background-color: #D5C3C3;
    height: 75 px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top:100px;
}

.footer img {
padding:4px;
display:inline;
}
.buy {    
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
}
.buy2 {
    background-color:black;
    float: left;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
.buy3 {
    float: left;
    height: 500px;
    width: 33%;
}
.buy4 {
    float: right;
    height: 500px;
    width: 33%;
}
.buy5 {
    background-color: yellow;
    float:left;
    height:500px;
}

/*Products*/

.wrapper{
    /* width: 100%; */
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    justify-content:center; //there are several options to position
    align-items:center;
    flex-wrap: wrap; //if the display gets to small, the cards will automaticly position on a different line

}
.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  max-width: 300px;
  /* margin: auto; */ //no more need because parent controlls position.
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
}

.price {
  color: grey;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding:20px;
}

.card button {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 12px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.card button:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.productName {
    font-size:68px;
    font-weight:lighter;
    padding:10px;

}

.productDes {
    padding:10px;
}

.newPrice {
 font-size: 32px; 
 color:#272727;
 font-weight:bold;
 padding:10px;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>


<center>
    <a href="blackfriday.html"><p class="blackFriday" style="background-color:#191616; color: white; font-weight:bold;">BLACK FRIDAY SALE!</p></a>
</center>
<div class="fadein">
    <img id="f3" src="banner2.jpg" alt="">
    <img id="f2" src="banner4.png" alt="">
    <img id="f1" src="banner5.jpg" alt="">
</div>

<!--Shop Bar-->
<!--*<div class="shopBar">
    <div class="Logo"><img src="Logo.png" height="75px;" alt=""/></div>
<div class="storeName"><p class="petstorename">Pet Store</p></div>
</div>-->

 <!--Buttons-->
<center>
    <p style="background-color:#9B3240; position:relative;"> <a href="index.html"><img class="Logo" src="Logo.png" height="55" alt=""/></a>
      <a href="food.html"><button class="button">food</button></a>
      <a href="toys.html"><button class="button">toys</button></a>
      <a href="pharmacy.html"><button class="button">pharmacy</button></a>
      <a href="holiday.html"><button class="button">holiday sale</button></a>
      <a href="about.html"><button class="button">about us</button></a>
    </p>
</center>

<!--Images-->
<!--Products-->
<p class="holidays">BLACK FRIDAY</p>

<center><p class="specialdogdeals">These Deals Won't Last Long!</p></center>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="card">
        <img src="collar.png" alt="Denim Jeans" style="width:100%">
        <p class="productName">Leather Collar</p>
        <p class="price">$<strike>9.99</strike> 
        <p class="newPrice">2.99</p></p>
        <p class="productDes">A comfty collar made with natural materials.</p>
        <p><button>Add to Cart</button></p>
        </div>
        

        <div class="card">
        <img src="collar.png" alt="Denim Jeans" style="width:100%">
        <p class="productName">Leather Collar</p>
        <p class="price">$<strike>9.99</strike> 
        <p class="newPrice">2.99</p></p>
        <p class="productDes">A comfty collar made with natural materials.</p>
        <p><button>Add to Cart</button></p>
        </div> 
    </div>


<!--Footer-->
<div class="footer">
    <center>
        <p style="font-weight: bold; line-height:75px;"> 
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/"><img src="instagram.png"  width="25" height="25" alt=""/></a>
            <a href="https://www.twitter.com/"><img src="twitter.png" width="25" height="25" alt=""/></a>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com"><img src="facebook.png" width="25" height="25" alt=""/></a>
        <img src="support-dog-icon.png" width="35"  style="margin-left:50px; margin-right:10px;" alt=""/>Contact (578) 239-8980
        </p>
       
    </center>
</div>


</b
```

Comment: Hi, I used your code however what this does is put all the cards centered but each card is put on a separate line. https://i.imgur.com/rR3Ljht.png

Comment: @flower28732 idk what you are doing wrong, but if you just had copy/paste my code into yours it would had run. I've edited my post with a code snipped, which show the right result...